# Consecutive if statement flow

Tags: c, if-statement, statements

```
if (srcbloc == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "warning!: memrip source is null!\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (destbloc == NULL) {
    destbloc = malloc(len);
}
if (srcbloc == destbloc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "warning!: srcbloc = destbloc\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (offset < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "warning!: offset = %i\n", offset);
}
if (len < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "warning!: len = %i\n", len);
}
```

I am wondering if all of the if statements will be tested when this program is run?

Comment: Have you tried running the code to find out?

Comment: Have you tried it with some debug logging?

Comment: There is absolutely no way for us to know without context for the value being checked.

Comment: Well, obviously if the first or third one is true, the program will exit and so the rest of the tests won't run. Since your question is so extraordinarily basic, perhaps there's something else you're really trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code

```
if (srcbloc == NULL) { /* <-- if this block is entered then, */
  fprintf(stderr, "warning!: memrip source is null!\n"); 
  exit(1); /* <-- Program will exit */ 
}
if (destbloc == NULL) {  /* <-- Allocate destbloc of len length. */
  destbloc = malloc(len); 
}
if (srcbloc == destbloc) { /* <-- if this block is entered then, */
  fprintf(stderr, "warning!: srcbloc = destbloc\n"); 
  exit(1); /* <-- Program will exit */ 
}
if (offset < 0) { 
  fprintf(stderr, "warning!: offset = %i\n", offset); 
}
if (len < 0) { 
  fprintf(stderr, "warning!: len = %i\n", len); 
}
```

So, if `(srcbloc == NULL)` or `(srcbloc == destbloc)` the program will warn (and exit). If any of the other tests match the warnings will be printed but the program will continue to process.